# react native android error SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 0

Tags: android, react-native, fetch

Error log:

```
blob:http://localhost:8081/d0cb8da3-cbda-4352-940d-9ad7827bfee6:55463 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 0
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at tryCallOne (blob:http://localhost:8081/d0cb8da3-cbda-4352-940d-9ad7827bfee6:21859:14)
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/d0cb8da3-cbda-4352-940d-9ad7827bfee6:21960:17
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/d0cb8da3-cbda-4352-940d-9ad7827bfee6:8761:21
    at _callTimer (blob:http://localhost:8081/d0cb8da3-cbda-4352-940d-9ad7827bfee6:8650:9)
    at _callImmediatesPass (blob:http://localhost:8081/d0cb8da3-cbda-4352-940d-9ad7827bfee6:8686:9)
    at Object.callImmediates (blob:http://localhost:8081/d0cb8da3-cbda-4352-940d-9ad7827bfee6:8905:14)
    at MessageQueue.__callImmediates (blob:http://localhost:8081/d0cb8da3-cbda-4352-940d-9ad7827bfee6:8239:18)
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/d0cb8da3-cbda-4352-940d-9ad7827bfee6:8066:18
    at MessageQueue.__guardSafe (blob:http://localhost:8081/d0cb8da3-cbda-4352-940d-9ad7827bfee6:8223:11)
```

Problem only on Android, react native. I use fetch, method post.

Example code:

```
fetch(config.server + "/api/districts", {
      method: "POST"
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ districts: res.data });
      });
```

Comment: check whether the data is valid json

Comment: @AravindS data is valid, I checked in console.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `.data`?

Answer (score 0):

It's just been problem with encoding in backend (UTF-8 without BOM).

Comment: i have the same issue . but it works fine in ios . what is the solution for this ?